# "Whole" vs. "entire"

Tags: differences

I wonder if there is a difference between the words "whole" and "entire". For example, the following sentences:

> - I spent my *whole* life waiting for you.
> - I spent my *entire* life waiting for you.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

“Whole” comes from “unhurt”, and means a single object that has not been subdivided.

“Entire” comes from “complete”, and means no part has been left out.

They are different when you are talking about collections of objects; the entire lot of cars, or the entire staff, since these are collections of distinct objects. You would say a whole loaf of bread or a whole person, since these are single objects not usually considered a collection of parts.

The expression “whole life” considers one’s life to be a single unit that has not been subdivided. An “entire life” means all the parts (years? experiences?) of a life. In this case either could be used.

Comment: perfect explaination

Answer (score 5):

In the context you are using the terms, they are interchangeable.

The only places you wouldn't be able to substitute *entire* are in idioms as in "on the whole" or "taken as a whole" or "the whole nine yards" and so on. Also, only *whole* works in the following sentence.

> The shark swallowed the tuna whole.

Comment: +1 Good point. They're generally very close synonyms, except in certain phrases/idioms.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few instances where the words are not synonyms. These include the botanical *entire*, meaning a leaf without an indented edge, or in farming parlance *entire* meaning uncastrated. In mathematics you could have a *whole* number, but not an entire one. But if you ignore these special meanings they are more or less interchangeable, except as pointed out by the other answerers.